# Assign two different random number series from list, with n percent probability of similar numbers

Tags: matlab, random, probability

Please first take a look at the image. We distribute some nodes in the network. The network also divided into 9 equal cells.

Image (simpified example): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRr8s.jpg

First I distribute my nodes in the field randomly. Now I want to assign each nodes (a,b,c ... ) 10 random value from the chlist. But the problem is node "a" and node "b" have to take 70% same values. In other word, if two nodes are in the same cell for example in [0,10;0,10] or [10,20;20,30] case, they have to have 70% same values.

Nothing has come to my mind unless assigned value for each cell by hand not on a random basis. Something like the below codes, although it's not precise, I just put it to see how I solved the problem.

```
xm=30;
ym=30;
n=15;
for i=1:1:n
S(i).xd=rand(1,1)*xm;
XR(i)=S(i).xd;
S(i).yd=rand(1,1)*ym;
YR(i)=S(i).yd;
end

for i=1:1:n
if ( 0 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=10 && 0 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=10)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

elseif ( 0 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=10 && 10 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=20)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 13];

elseif ( 0 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=10 && 20 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=30)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13];

elseif ( 10 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=20 && 10 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=10)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 13 15];

elseif ( 10 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=20 && 20 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=20)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 13];

elseif ( 10 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=20 && 30 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=30)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13];

elseif ( 20 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=30 && 10 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=10)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 13 15];

elseif ( 20 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=30 && 20 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=20)
    chlist(i, :)=[3 4 5 6 7 10 11 13 15 16];

elseif ( 20 <= XR(i) &&  XR(i)<=30 && 30 <= YR(i) && YR(i)<=30)
    chlist(i, :)=[1 2 4 7 8 9 10 11 12 15];
end
end
```

Or another way I could do it is by using the following code:

```
for i=1:n
chlist(i,:)= randperm(13,10);
end
```

Since nodes are picking 10 values out of 13, for sure they have 7 similar values, which can work similar to 70% similarity. But still inside each cell we have more than 2 values it may not work.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Let's start by showing what you have done so far. Distributing the nodes between cells is easy, right? Randomly picking 10 values from `Chlist` for each node is also easy. So this would be a good first step.

Comment: By the way, if *three* nodes share the same cell, do all of them have to share 70% of their values, or does each pair of nodes have to have 70% of values equal independent of other pairs in the cell? And does it have to be exactly 70%, or _at least_ 70%?

Comment: If three or even more nodes share the same cell all of them must have at least 70% similar values. In fact I did the randomly distribution part and then based on their X Y position in the field I managed to assign the value by hand. But I want to make in truly random.

Comment: Okay, so how about adding some code for starters, and then we'll see how we can improve it?

Comment: Please take a look at the edited question. I try to show how I solved it temporarily.